# Facing problem to transfer data from SQL Server table to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to transfer data from SQL Server table to SnowFlake Database.

https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/article/how-to-set-up-a-linked-server-from-sql-server-to-snowflake

I have made ODBC 64 Bit Snowflake System DNS and try to make Linked Server but not successful complete. Facing error

Comment: I think you forgot to provide the error there Imran - You'll need to provide more information around what you have tried and the error you are seeing.

Comment: Is this for a large-scale movement of data from SQL to Snowflake?  If so, I wouldn't recommend using a linked server.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Mike W. This is not a good approach if you are loading a lot of data. You are best doing something like BCP'ing the data out of SQL Server and staging it in S3 or Data Lake, then copying the data into Snowflake. You are going to get the most throughput using this method.